# Dynamically set the position of a Button

Tags: ios, button

My problem is I want to set position of a Button dynamically. For example I had three textviews and 3 labels displayed initially with Submit and cancel buttons when the page loads. When we click on a Button three more pickerviews were displaying. My problem is when I click on the button Submit and Cancel needs to be displayed below the the pickerviews. Simply saying I want to change the Submit and cancel buttons positions dynamically. Its working fine at the time of loading. The problem comes when I click on the button to load the Pickerviews. Here is the piece of code.

```
- (IBAction)clicktoshowpickers:(id)sender {
    _projectpicker.hidden = NO;
    _taskspicker.hidden = NO;
    _subtaskspicker.hidden = NO;
    if(_projectpicker.hidden)
    {
        submitdimension.frame = CGRectMake( 83, 232, 75, 600 );
        canceldimensions.frame = CGRectMake(175, 232, 75, 600);
    }
    else{
        submitdimension.frame = CGRectMake( 83, 937, 75, 600 );
        canceldimensions.frame = CGRectMake(175, 937, 75, 600);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set 3 picker view in your main view ???.. ok ..simple set Y of button _projectpicker.frame.origin.y + _projectpicker.frame.size.height

Comment: Could you please elaborate the answer

Comment: It sounds like you want to move all the controls up and down as the picker views come into and out of view. Is that right? If so, it would be easier to put these controls inside a `UIScrollView`, then change the `scrollIndicatorInset` or the `contentInset` of the `UIScrollView` as the picker views animate into and out of view.

Comment: what @Aaron said, or at least use layout with constraints. If you write code to move the button positions it's a huge reinvention of the wheel and you have to test on iPad, landscape, 3.5 and 4" screens, and fix bugs forever.

Comment: Can you post the declaration and definition of `submitdimension` and `canceldimensions`?  Also +1 on you should be doing this with `NSAnimation` and constraints.